# Парсинг json в массиве php

Tags: php, json

Нужно вывести, например, id из списка с "m" = "name":
    `[
    {
    "id":["13521701706"],
    "o":[572],
    "g":10,
    "l":["5387586517006391497"],
    "m":"name",
    "u":"oaa",
    "p":5198.45,
    "d":["t7xv"],
    "f":[0],
    "y":[8],
    "n":[0],
    "b":["76561198316129582"],
    "h":11
    },
    {
    "id":["13536358084"],
    "o":[149],
    "g":2,
    "l":["12316831292893548603"],
    "c":1,
    "m":"name2",
    "z":2,
    "e":"FN",
    "u":"qao",
    "p":4279.56,
    "d":["udeg"],
    "f":["0.03535882"],
    "y":[8],
    "n":[0],
    "w":19,
    "b":["76561198309954639"],
    "h":6
    }
]`
Как это сделать(желательно на PHP)?

Comment: С чем у вас возникли затруднения?

Comment: С выводом какого-либо элемента из этого массива

Comment: Добавте ваш код прямо  вопрос и покажите в каком месте у вас не получилось.

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно брать этот код из другого файла и происходит ошибка "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php on line 5" (То, что написали ниже работает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дока http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

```
$str = '[
{
    "id":["13521701706"],
    "o":[572],
    "g":10,
    "l":["5387586517006391497"],
    "m":"name",
    "u":"oaa",
    "p":5198.45,
    "d":["t7xv"],
    "f":[0],
    "y":[8],
    "n":[0],
    "b":["76561198316129582"],
    "h":11
},
{
    "id":["13536358084"],
    "o":[149],
    "g":2,
    "l":["12316831292893548603"],
    "c":1,
    "m":"name2",
    "z":2,
    "e":"FN",
    "u":"qao",
    "p":4279.56,
    "d":["udeg"],
    "f":["0.03535882"],
    "y":[8],
    "n":[0],
    "w":19,
    "b":["76561198309954639"],
    "h":6
}
]';

$json = json_decode($str, true);
foreach ($json as $el) {
    if ($el['m'] == 'name') {
        var_dump($el['id'][0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но почему при $str = "filename.json"; происходит ошибка "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING) in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php on line 4"

Comment: $str содержит строку но не данные из файла. Вам надо прочитать данные из файла. Самый простой способ
$str = file_get_contents("filename.json")